# How to open a file with a specific application by python?

Tags: python

For example,
I want to open a file D:\happy\0.pyw
My code is below

```py
import os

def open_app(dir):
    os.startfile(dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b=r'D:\happy\0.pyw'
    open_app(b)
```

But here I want to edit the file with IDLE, not just click open it. How to change the code?

```py
b=r'D:\happy\0.pyw'
```

with

```py
D:\python\idle.pyw'
```

will fail.

Comment: `os.startfile('Your/IDLE/PATH/idle.exe', 'D:\haapy\0.pyw')` does this code work?

Comment: `will fail.` → and what is error message and traceback?

Comment: To Keijack, the problem is there is no program with idle.exe, only idle.py idle.pyw idle.bat

Comment: When I open a .py document, I click the right part of the mouse and choose edit with IDLE, it works. I want to find how to do this as a code in python, thank you.

Comment: To rzlvmp, you know my aim and the code will not work as expected.